# How to deal with the bracket-form include directives in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, include, include-path

could you please help me out by answering my following question about the Visual Studio include behavior?

I create a new C++ Project, which references an already existing one, whose source files should not be altered. I end up with the following file
structure:

```
-MyProject
+---MyProject.sln
+---MyProject.vcxproj
+---MyProject.cpp
+---CommonHeader.h

-ExistingProject
+---project
+---+---ExistingProject.vcxproj
+---source
+---+---ExistingProject1.h
+---+---ExistingProject2.h
+---+---ExistingProject1.c
+---+---ExistingProject2.c
```

At the beginning, i could not even compile the ExistingProject. Within the ExistingProject1.c, the following include statement exists:

```
#include <ExistingProject1.h>
```

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(v=vs.100).aspx) i learned, that in case of the bracket-includes, Visual Studio does not look for the Header within the same directory as the file that contains the include statement. So my first question would be:

> 1) Is it true, that i have to add the "../source/"-Directory to the Include Directories of the ExistingProject.vcxproj, although the Header files are already added to the visual Studio project?

To use the structures and functions of the ExistingProject, i have to include the ExistingProject2.h into my MyProject.cpp. But within the ExistingProject2.h, the same include Statement

```
#include <ExistingProject1.h>
```

exists. This leads to my second question:

> 2) Is it true, that i have to add the "../ExistingProject/source/-Directory to the Include Directories of MyProject.vcxproj project as well?

And now comes the really strange problem. If a certain define is set, which has to be set within MyProject, the ExistingProject2.h also includes an external header file via

```
#include <CommonHeader.h>
```

Which has to be defined by the dependent project. This leads to my last question:

> 3) Is it true, that i have only the following two options to compile with this external header file?
>
> 1. I have to copy my CommonHeader.h into the "ExistingProject\source\"-Directory during checkout.
> 2. I have to add the "."-Directory to the Include Directories of MyProject.vcxproj project and i have to add the "../../MyProject/"-Directory to the Include Directories of ExistingProject.vcxproj.

The second option just makes no sense. Is the first one really my only option to deal with this bracket-form include of an external header file?

And: Shouldn't be at least the location, next to the vcxproj file, be within the include directories of a header file, which is used within that project?

Sorry for the stupid spelling. I am a really bad explainer.
Wish you all a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1):

When you put `#include <header.h>` - Visual Studio will search for it in all specified include paths in project settings, this includes default paths, where Windows SDK and standard library resides. See this screenshot, as example: [image: nclude]

If you put `C:\path1\path2` to include directory, you might end up using `#include <..\path1.h>`

In case of `#include "quotes.h"` - Visual studio will search for files only in project directory, where you store your files. If you put additional files in some sub-folders in project - you always need to specify relative path (like `#include "subfolder\header.h"`).

Let me know, if you need further clarification on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Allgaeuer do not forget to upvote\accept answer, if it helps you

Comment: I just edited my third question, because it would not be enough to add the "."-Directoy to the Include Directories of MyProject.vcxproj. Could you have a second look?

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact definition of how Visual Studio uses bracket includes (`<>`) versus quote includes (`""`):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp .

Summary: Brackets `<>` will stick strictly to the "include directories" settings.  Quotes `""` will also do "include directories", but will first search local project directories.